# Bug with multiplayer, alliances and emergency wars that only affects planes?

Tags: civilization-6, civilization-6-rise-and-fall

Not sure if there is some weird mechanic I'm missing here, but we are playing local multiplayer vs AI and after I took a city state there was a World Congress to condemn me, which passed and declared a city state emergency, and then on the next turn, after everyone declared war on me (I have a lot of territory right now), I can't attack Japan with any of my planes. Only planes. I'm so confused. He has like 12 death robots and I can't attack a single one, but only if I try with planes. I can attack him with my navy and land units, but not planes. It's not a vision bug, even if the planes are right next to his units I can't attack.

Things that might be affecting this (?) that I can think of:

- Before the World Congress, my partner was allied with Japan's partner
- In the turn before WC I made peace with two Civs that are not Japan
  or Scotland (Japan's ally)

I've reloaded the save multiple times and tried to do things differently, but still can't attack Japan.

Anyone know what's happening? This is in super late game, if it matters.

It still says my partner has a military alliance with Japan's ally even though we are at war, also.

Comment: Are they anti-air only planes by any chance? Make sure they're bombers (I assume you know this, but I've made the mistake before :P)

Comment: Both bombers and fighters can't hit them :( we just abandoned the game (on turn 440.. so sad). haven't seen this bug mentioned anywhere online so not sure how it actually happened or if it will be fixed